# How to get an array having unique ranges from the array with duplicated ranges?

Tags: arrays, swift, set, range, hashable

I can get an array of unique numbers from the array having duplicated numbers

```
let arrayWithReapeats = [1, 2, 3, 7, 3]
let unique = Array(Set(arrayWithReapeats))
```

I need an array having unique ranges

```
Range<String.Index>
```

from the array having duplicated ranges for instance like this.

```
let arrayWithReapeatsIdexes = [1..<5, 3..<9, 9..<25, 3..<9]
```

I cannot use the same approach with Set since only String, Int, Double, and Bool are hashable by default. How to make ranges hashable to be able to use the approach above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *only* requirement for the hash value is

> `x == y` implies `x.hashValue == y.hashValue`

which means that the "trivial" hash function

```
extension Range : Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

is valid and works:

```
let arrayWithRepeatingIndexes = [1..<5, 3..<9, 9..<25, 3..<9]
let arrayWithUniqueIndexes = Array(Set(arrayWithRepeatingIndexes))

print(arrayWithUniqueIndexes)
// [Range(1..<5), Range(3..<9), Range(9..<25)]
```

You can also use the fact that the *distance* from start to end
index is a integer type (and thus has a hash value):

```
public var hashValue: Int {
    return startIndex.distanceTo(endIndex).hashValue
}
```

or compute the hash value from the description string (such as "3..<9"):

```
public var hashValue: Int {
    return description.hashValue
}
```

You'll have to figure out which one is the most effective for your purpose.

Comment: I have tried also with array of NSRanges instead of the array of type Ranges, it did not work with NSRange instead of Range in extension - NSRange is not conform to protocol Equatable. What should I change ? (should I ask this as a new question ?)

Comment: @VYT That means that you have to implement `==` for NSRange.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Equatable {
    func unique() -> [Generator.Element] {
    var seen: Array<Generator.Element> = []
        return  filter {
        if seen.contains($0){
            return false
        } else {
            seen.append($0)
            return true
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try if there is no way to use Set.